# Codeigniter 3 form validation into array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I'm using codeigniter 3, and I'm trying to use the form_validation library.

Basically, if validation fails, I'm catching the input data and then sending it back to the form.

So I'm sticking all form data in an array, like so:

```
            // add input data to array
            $org_data = array(
                'org_id'            => $this->input->post('org_id'),
                'p_org_id'          => $this->input->post('p_org_id'),
                'account_ref'       => $this->input->post('account_ref'),
                'org_name'          => $this->input->post('org_name'),
                'address1'          => $this->input->post('address1'),
                'address2'          => $this->input->post('address2'),
                'address3'          => $this->input->post('address3'),
                'town'              => $this->input->post('town'),
                'county'            => $this->input->post('county'),
                'pcode'             => $this->input->post('pcode'),
                'phone'             => $this->input->post('phone'),
                'support_email'     => $this->input->post('support_email'),
                'notify_return'     => $this->input->post('notify_return'),
                'notify_email'      => $this->input->post('notify_email'),
                'email_interval'    => $this->input->post('email_interval'),
                'renewal_date'      => $this->input->post('renewal_date'),
                'login_reminder'    => $this->input->post('login_reminder'),
                'default_fireaware' => $this->input->post('default_fireaware'),
                'open_training_url' => $this->input->post('open_training_url'),
            );
```

All fine!

Now, to send the data back to the form, I am using the below.

```
        $this->data['org_id'] = array(
            'name'  => 'org_id',
            'id'    => 'org_id',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('org_id'),
        );
```

BUT

I don't want to create one of these for every input, so ideally I'd like to use a loop to create these. But I cant get it to work, I am getting undefined variable errors.

This is the loop in progress:

```
        foreach($org_data as $key => $value){

            $this->data['$key'] = array(
                'name'  => '$key',
                'id'    => '$key',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('$value'),
            );  

        }
```

Can I use a loop to do this?

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Every variable, so I get this: Message: Undefined variable: org_id for each one

Answer (score 0):

use validation like this

```
$config = array(
           array(
                 'field'   => 'username', 
                 'label'   => 'Username', 
                 'rules'   => 'required'
              ),
           array(
                 'field'   => 'password', 
                 'label'   => 'Password', 
                 'rules'   => 'required'
              ),
           array(
                 'field'   => 'passconf', 
                 'label'   => 'Password Confirmation', 
                 'rules'   => 'required'
              ),   
           array(
                 'field'   => 'email', 
                 'label'   => 'Email', 
                 'rules'   => 'required'
              )
        );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $data['errors']             = validation_errors();
            $this->load->view('yourview', $data);
          } else {
            $userData = $this->input->post();
            $this->load->view('yourview', $data);

        }
```

Comment: OK, and then how will i repopulate the form with values already input?

Comment: read this http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#repopulatingform

Comment: you can repoplute the fields by set_value('field name')

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, if validation fails, I'm catching the input data and then
>   sending it back to the form.

yeah i think this is the part to clarify - you don't need to do that at all -- thats the advantage of using set_value('fieldName'), it automatically echoes out the value. Same - on the form - with form_error( 'fieldName' ) it will display the field specific error message.